# Set selected ListView TextColor in Xamarin.Forms Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to set the selected Text Color of a `ListViewItem` to white in Xamarin Forms Android.

On iOS I can do it with custom ListViewRenderer and a custom UITableViewSource where I set the HighlightedTextColor.

```
cell.TextLabel.HighlightedTextColor = UIColor.FromRGB(255, 255, 255);
```

Is there an equivalent for this in Android? I already tried it with the [`Resource.Attribute` `ColorControlActivated`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Resource+Attribute/), but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Android Color Class is in the root of the Resource Class         
     ListViewItem.TextColor = Android.Resource.Color.White;
```

Comment: Add explanation of your answer. It is right now in LQ review.